# Improve precision/recall in unbalanced dataset with tidymodels

Tags: r, tidyverse, tidymodels

I have the following code:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(tidymodels)
library(readxl)
library(themis)
library(baguette) # bagged trees
library(future) # parallel processing & decrease computation time


df <- read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/norhther/datasets/main/pacientes.csv")

sapply(df, function(x) sum(is.na(x))/nrow(df))


df <- df %>%
  select(ICC, CPI, Valvulopatía,
         `Vascuopatía periférica`, ACxFA,
         HTA, EPOC, `AVC/AIT`, Demencia,
         `Osteoporosis/Fx patol`, Neoplasia,
         IRC, DBT, `Numero antecedentes`, Hb,
         `Nº medicacion habitual`, `Reserva Funcional (METS)`,
         `MNA (Nutricion)`, MMSE, Fragilidad, Dependencia,
         `Normal Gait speed`, Charlson, ASA, Complejidad,
         `Sobrevida al mes`, `Mujer`, `Vive con`, `Especialidad`,
         `Tipo de Anestesia`, `Transfusión`, `Creat`, `INR`)


df <- df %>%
  mutate(across(1:13, as_factor)) %>%
  mutate(Complejidad = as_factor(Complejidad),
         `Sobrevida al mes` = as_factor(`Sobrevida al mes`),
         Mujer = as_factor(Mujer),
         Especialidad = as_factor(Especialidad),
         `Tipo de Anestesia` = as_factor(`Tipo de Anestesia`),
         Transfusión = as_factor(Transfusión))

df <- df %>%
  mutate(`Vive con` = as.numeric(`Vive con`)) %>%
  drop_na()


data_split <- initial_split(df, prop = 0.8, strata = `Sobrevida al mes`)
train_data <- training(data_split)
test_data <- testing(data_split)

rec <- recipe(`Sobrevida al mes` ~ ., data = train_data)

prep_recipe <- rec %>% prep()

cv <- vfold_cv(train_data)

set.seed(100)


mod_rf <-rand_forest() %>%
  set_engine("ranger",
             num.threads = parallel::detectCores(), 
             importance = "permutation", 
             verbose = TRUE) %>% 
  set_mode("classification") %>% 
  set_args(trees = 1000)

wflow_bag <- workflow() %>% 
  add_recipe(rec) %>%
  add_model(mod_rf)

plan(multisession)

fit_rf <- fit_resamples(
  wflow_bag,
  cv,
  metrics = metric_set(accuracy, kap, recall, precision),
  control = control_resamples(verbose = TRUE,
                              save_pred = TRUE,
                              extract = function(x) x)
)

collect_metrics(fit_rf)
```

However, as the dataset is unbalanced, I'm getting the following results:

```
# A tibble: 4 × 6
  .metric   .estimator    mean     n std_err .config             
  <chr>     <chr>        <dbl> <int>   <dbl> <chr>               
1 accuracy  binary       0.953    10  0.0223 Preprocessor1_Model1
2 kap       binary       0         4  0      Preprocessor1_Model1
3 precision binary     NaN         0 NA      Preprocessor1_Model1
4 recall    binary       0         4  0      Preprocessor1_Model1
```

I would like to improve these metrics, but I already tried using SMOTE, and it didn't work so well (using themis library). Also I don't know if my interpretation of `as_factor`is correct. I used it on binary factors, however there are also 1-10 scales that I don't know if it should be a ordered factor or is it ok to be a numeric value.

Answer (score 0):

There's not anything wrong in your code that I can see.

Your training set has 11 events out of 186. Once it is resampled, the number goes does and you are getting notes with:

> While computing binary `precision()`, no predicted events were detected (i.e. `true_positive + false_positive = 0`).
> Precision is undefined in this case, and `NA` will be returned.
> Note that 2 true event(s) actually occured for the problematic event level, '0'.

You can try one of the upsampling tools in the [themis package](https://themis.tidymodels.org) to increase the number of events but, with these data, you might have to set your expectations low for performance.

Comment: I would like to ask, is there a difference in modeling in tidymodels between having a binary factor labeled as 0 and 1 and those numeric values? And also ordered factors, because there are some scales that go from 0 to 6, clearly ordered. Adding that order could help, or is it irrelevant?